# Can't Regenerate X-XSRF-TOKEN cookies in my production system

Tags: php, laravel, cookies, next.js

Here are my software versions:

- Sanctum Version: ^2.14.1
- Laravel Version: 9.0
- PHP Version: ^8.0.2
- Database Driver & Version:  Heroku pgql version 14.4

#### Description

I have two folders:
`backend` for laravel-breeze https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/starter-kits#laravel-breeze
`frontend` for next.js application.

I follow all the instruction given through `breeze-next` and my development seems perfectly fine.

I also successfully deployed my laravel-api with the helps of this articles. And configured necessary database to established a connection
https://dev.to/moose_said/deploy-laravel-projects-with-database-for-free-5778

[image]

I separately deployed my frontend next.js in to Vercel and configured the NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_URL into my deployed laravel-api in Heroku:

[image]

#### First Problem that I solved

I managed to fix the Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) in my backend with this implementation in Laravel
[image]

and also add the `FRONTEND_URL` in Heroku production and it works
[image]

#### Second Problem

`CSRF token mismatch`

This is the error also that I somehow fixed but I'm not sure this is the good idea

[image]

I also changed the session driver into `cookie`

[image]

### PROBLEM

So, now I can register but cannot generate the cookies for my headers like `X-XSRF-TOKEN`. I also tried to login but cannot regenerate the cookies need to authenticate the user. There is no problem in my development only in my production system:

[image]

It says that:

> this attempt to set cookie via a set-cookie header was blocked because it had "samesite=lux" but came from a cross site response which was not a response to a top level navigation

What can I try next?

This the actual repository: https://github.com/acatzk/sph-els-joshua

Comment: This the actual repository https://github.com/acatzk/sph-els-joshua

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved the problem just by adding these in the `config/session.php`
[image]

[image]